# Setting active page in Power BI report

Tags: powerbi

I have 4 pages in my report. I need to display different page based on the website that the customer is currently viewing. Originally, I had 4 different configurations which was loading the report 4 times. Of course, that had a huge effect on the performance and simply isn't the right solution.

At first, I have tried this

```
var report = powerbi.embed($reportContainer.get(0), embedConfigurationMain);
report.setFilters([basicFilterMain, stocktakeIdFilterMain]);
var page = report.page('ReportSectionxxxxxxxxx');
page.setActive();
```

But it still displays the default page of the report.

I then found someone with a similar problem here https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/set-active-page-in-report-with-JavaScript-API/m-p/93716#M... and tried the suggested solution, but I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setActive' of undefined
```

I then went on to check Power BI Playground and used the exact code that they supply there, which is

```
report.getPages()
.then(function (pages) {
    pages[0].setActive()
        .then(function () {
            Log.logText("Active page was set to: \"" + pages[0].displayName + "\"");
        })
        .catch(function (errors) {
            Log.log(errors);
        });
})
.catch(function (errors) {
    Log.log(errors);
});
```

But still no joy, nothing happens. Not even getting messages in the console.

What is the proper way of setting the active report page in JavaScript API? I am using to most recent version of Power BI Embedded SDK.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for your purpose. As you said you have different website and you wants to show different page in your report based on the request comes from which website.

You can list browser URL for different page in your report from power BI service. Just go to different page of your report, you will get page wise links. You can see that a same page will always generate unique URL in the browser. So, if you have 4 page in your report, you will get 4 unique URL from the browser.

Now, you can set destination URL (page specific) in your website's link. Hope this tricks will work.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the "undefined" error you are seeing is `pages[0].setActive()`.

Change to:

```
report.getPages()
.then(function (page) {
    page.setActive()
        .then(function () {
            Log.logText("Active page was set to: \"" + page.displayName + "\"");
        })
        .catch(function (errors) {
            Log.log(errors);
        });
})
.catch(function (errors) {
    Log.log(errors);
});
```